# Redux Storing an array of users

Tags: reactjs, redux

im currently stuck with some feature on a project of mine, i want to store an array of objects in redux, first on my component when the user completes the data i create a new object>

```
handleChange({target: {id, value}}) {
    this.setState(
        state => ({
            user: new User(Object.assign(state.user, {[id]: value}))
        })
    );
}
```

then an action is dispached,

```
dispatch => ({
    requestSaveUser: user => dispatch(requestSaveUser(user)),
```

but the problem comes, i want to start creating an array of users to show them on the same page, the idea is to start loding users and being able to show them in a table but this way i get the last user changed by the new one, here is my redux:

```
export default function user(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_SAVE_REQUESTED:
            return {...state, users: action.user};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your want to append the new user to the users table :

```
return {...state, users: [ ...state.users, action.user ]};
```

Comment: Im having a problem with the name in that, second user changes the name of the first for example if first user is John and second is Mark John name is changed to  M

Comment: In handleChange : `user: { ...state.user, [id]: value}` or you can keep `Object.assign` but first param should be a new object : `{}`

Comment: user: { ...state.user, [id]: value} solved it but i want to use object assing can you explain me a bit more what is the problem?

Comment: The first parameter of `Object.assign` is the target, if you don't pass a new object (`{}`), you assign your new value to the old user. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)